# Is a static object inside a function re-initialized when its initialization value is dynamic

Tags: c++

given the following code:

```
void some_class::some_function(void) {
    static I2cU8U8RemoteRegister ctl(Registers::IND_ACC_CTL, *this);
..
}
```

does ctl get reinitialized if "this" changes, i.e. some_function is called with different object than it was called the first time?

Thanks for any help on this issue.

Kind regards, Steve

Comment: If it did, it would defeat the purpose of `static` local variables, which is to preserve its state from one call to another.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> does ctl get reinitialized if "this" changes, i.e. some_function is
> called with different object than it was called the first time?

No.

Local static variables are initialized at most once, at the first function/method call.